# Oracle Sql Query to get the list of customers who placed most recent orders

Tags: oracle

My complete question is that I have a customers table with customer_id , orders table with order_id  and order_date and customer_id ,order_details table with order_id and item_id and items table having item_id .So I need oracle sql query to get the list of customers who placed most recent purchases..Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need a database structure also?

Comment: This question lacks a *lot* of necessary information - see http://www.sscce.org for instructions on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's make some basic assumptions:

- you have a CUSTOMERS table
- you have an ORDERS table containing a customer_id (foreign key) and a order_date

Then, this should do the trick:

```
  SELECT customer_name, most_recent_order 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      c.customer_name, 
      MAX(o.order_date) AS most_recent_order
    FROM customers c
    JOIN orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
    GROUP BY c.customer_name
  )
  ORDER by most_recent_order desc
```

Comment: Sorry for providing only half information.My complete question is that I have a customers table with customer_id , orders table with order_id and customer_id ,order_details table with order_id and item_id and items table having item_id .So I need list of customer(s) who placed the most recent order(s).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT cust_id, first_name, last_name FROM customers ORDER BY orderdate DESC;